# MySql find country via geometry / spatial data

Tags: mysql, geometry, spatial, border

i want request my db with LAT/LON an get back a countrycode.
i have the world borders in a mysql database (converted shapefile from djangoproject.com) as geometry datafield.
When using

```
SELECT countyname FROM `world` WHERE Contains(ogc_geom, POINT(-18, 64))
```

i get back not only "iceland" (which is true) but also greenland, russia and usa.
I tried other points (point in mongolia founds also in china and russia), tried using intersects(), checked with multipolygons...

good ideas?
thanks, stefan

Comment: consider posting on gis.stackexchange.com Or, save yourself a lot of time and use something like http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Comment: We have no way of answering this question without knowing what data is stored in the database. Please post a [minimal sample](http://sscce.org/): complete, concise and reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do this only using MySQL. If you can interface the MySQL data with a scripting language, the n you can try the following.
Generate an image of the world map. Each pixel in the image will store the country id. You can lookup the country details from the MySQL db using this id.